# How can I get the SVN file size update info?

Tags: svn

As far as I know, svn stores a pristine set of files in .svn and when updating, we'll get a difference between svn server and current working copy and update that.

My question is, how can we get the file size to be updated between two revision?

example:

```
Rev 1: A.txt has "a"
Rev 2: A.txt has "b"
Rev 3: A.txt has "bbb"
```

so for 1 and 2, if I do a diff, it'll show something like

```
A.txt

-a
+b
```

right?

That's the patch that'll be transferred from svn server to my local working copy if I update file A from R1 to R2, how can I know the size of the patch, in bytes maybe?

I've tried svn diff, svn status -u and svn mergeinfo, does not seems to have what I'm looking for.

Comment: The size of the patch will be approximately the size of the diff that you perform. But that's not necessarily the amount of data that'll be transferred because, unless you're using `file:///`, there's compression over the wire (either built in or in the case of HTTP, optional through Apache modules). What problem are you attempting to solve with this?

Comment: @alroc I'm trying to create a svn user interface using sharpsvn, which is why I put the tag there in the first place, and I am hoping the ui to display a progress bar of totalBytesTransferred/totalBytesToBeTransferred and another progress bar of totalBytesTransferredForCurrentFile/totalBytesToBeTransferredForCurrentFile. I can get every bit of information I need except for totalBytesToBeTransferred and totalBytesToBeTransferredForCurrentFile